# Eliminar un registro con AJAX y PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo una tabla, agrego un botón de eliminar y quiero eliminar cada fila cuando se hace clic en el botón de eliminar con la función ajax, lo que pasa al presionar boton eliminar es que me muestra el mensaje que el registro ha sido eliminados pero este no se elimina, este es mi archivo donde se encuentra la tabla de los registros y mi boton de eliminar:

```
<?php
require_once("conexion.php");
$link = conectar();
//Tuve que crear un archivo nuevo que solo contenga la tabla, así supongo que se nos hara más fácil a 
todos
//Ahora si podran encontar información al respecto :D, me disculpo por el otro metodo.
?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellido</th>
        <th>Pais</th>
        <th>RFC</th>
        <th>Editar</th>
        <th>Eliminar</th>
    </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody">
            <?php

            //Ahora en el mismo Tbody hacemos la consulta para mostrar los registros
            $query = "SELECT * FROM avion";
            $result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
                //Mientas la consulta se ejecuta vamos guardando en cada Boton de editar, un arreglo
                //con la información del registro
                $datos=$row[0]."||".
                       $row[1]."||".
                       $row[2]."||".
                       $row[3]."||".
                       $row[4]."||".
                       $row[5];
                       //El en el metodo onClick mandamos llamar la funcion AgregaEdit que tenemos en
                       //el archivo Practica1.php y en el parametro le damos la cadena datos que
                       //generamos aqui arriba.
         ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row[0] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row[1] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row[2] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row[4] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row[5] ?></td>
            <td>
        <button type="button" name="btnEditar" id="btnEditar" onclick="agregaEdit('<?php echo $datos 
?>')">Editar
                </button>
            </td>
            <td>
                // ESTE ES MI BOTON ELIMINAR
                <button type="button" name="btnEliminar" id="btnEliminar" 
                onClick="javascript:Eliminar('<?php echo $row[0] ?>')">Eliminar
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
         ?>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Lo siguiente es mi función ajax (Soy nueva en esto apenas estoy aprendiendo y me gustaría que me puedan a ayudar)

```
function Eliminar(){
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Eliminar.php",
                cache: false,
                data:,
                error:function(){
                    $("#resultado").html("Error");
                },
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $("#resultado").html("Cargando...");

                },
                success: function(okay){
                $('#tabla2').load('tabla.php');
                $("#resultado").html("Registro Eliminado");
                }

        });
    }
```

Y por utimo muestro mi archivo Eliminar.php donde se encuentra mi consulta de bd

```
<?php
require_once("conexion.php");
$link = conectar();
$query = "DELETE FROM avion WHERE Id='$_POST[txtID]'";

echo $consulta=mysqli_query($link, $query);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al realizar la petición has olvidado enviar el valor del **txtID**.

```
function Eliminar(txtID) {
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Eliminar.php",
            cache: false,
            data: {txtID},
            error:function(){
                $("#resultado").html("Error");
            },
            beforeSend:function(){
                $("#resultado").html("Cargando...");
            },
            success: function(okay){
            $('#tabla2').load('tabla.php');
            $("#resultado").html("Registro Eliminado");
            }

    });
}
```